# Query or function to round off the value

Tags: oracle, plsql

I just looking for a query or function to round off my value as shown here:

- Amount - 3162.145
- Expected output - 3163

Kindly suggest to get the expected value with a query or any round off function.

Thanks
Abinnaya

Comment: What is expected output if amount = 3162.645?

Comment: For 3162.645 also same Expected output - 3163

Comment: OK, so - what's the rule which leads from input to output? Truncate and add 1 (as answer which is now deleted suggests)?

Comment: @Littlefoot I deleted because it doesn't work with integer number, i.e. 3162.0 would give 3163. I added new answer which is correct now

Comment: For Ex : if the values are from  3.1 to 3.9 for all i need  4 as output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the `CEIL` function

```
select CEIL(3162.145) from dual; -- result 3163
select CEIL(3162) from dual; -- result 3162
```